# How to send multiple messages in parallel and consume them at one shot using RabbitMQ?

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

New to RabbitMQ. After browsing through multiple sites I could construct the  following program to send multiple messages in parallel.

> sender.py

```
import pika
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import multiprocessing


class MetaClass(type):
    _instance = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Singleton Design pattern
        if the instance already exist don't create one!
        """
        if cls not in cls._instance:
            cls._instance[cls] = super(MetaClass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            return cls._instance[cls]


class RabbitMQConfigure(metaclass=MetaClass):
    def __init__(self, queue='durable_task_queue', host="localhost", routing_key="durable_task_queue", exchange=""):
        """
        Configure RabbitMQ server
        """
        self.queue = queue
        self.host = host
        self.routing_key = routing_key
        self.exchange = exchange


class RabbitMQ(Thread):
    def __init__(self, rabbit_mq_server, queue1):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.rabbit_mq_server = rabbit_mq_server
        self.queue1 = queue1

        self._connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(self.rabbit_mq_server.host))
        self._channel = self._connection.channel()
        self._channel.queue_declare(queue=self.rabbit_mq_server.queue, durable=True)

    def __enter__(self):
        print("__enter__")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print("__exit__")
        self._connection.close()

    def publish(self, message=""):
        print("Inside publish method...")
        self._channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.rabbit_mq_server.exchange,
                                    routing_key=self.rabbit_mq_server.routing_key, body=message)
        print(" [x] Sent %r" % message)

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while i <= 5:
            # Get the work from the queue and expand the tuple
            message = self.queue1.get()
            print("Inside run method...")
            print("Going to call publish method...")
            print("Message value:" + message)
            self.publish(message=message)
            i += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rabbit_mq_server = RabbitMQConfigure(queue='durable_task_queue', host="localhost", routing_key='durable_task_queue',
                                         exchange="")
    # with RabbitMQ(rabbit_mq_server, message="Hello World!") as rabbitmq:
    #     rabbitmq.publish()

    queue1 = Queue()
    no_of_CPUs = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    messages = []
    for i in range(5):
        messages.append("Hello world1" + str(i))

    for x in range(2):
        with RabbitMQ(rabbit_mq_server, queue1) as rabbitmq:
            # rabbitmq.daemon = True
            rabbitmq.start()

    # Put the tasks into the queue as a tuple
    for message in messages:
        queue1.put(message)
    # Causes the main thread to wait for the queue to finish processing all the tasks
    queue1.join()
```

But this program always produce the following output without being sending any messages:

```
E:\rabbitmq\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:/rabbitmq/work_queues/new_task.py
__enter__
__exit__
__enter__
__exit__ Inside run method...Inside run method... Going to call publish method... Going to call publish method...

Message value:Hello world11Message value:Hello world10 Inside publish method...

Inside publish method... Exception in thread Exception in thread Thread-3: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner Thread-1: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()   File "E:/rabbitmq/work_queues/new_task.py", line 79, in run self.run()   File "E:/rabbitmq/work_queues/new_task.py", line 79, in run
    self.publish(message=message)   File "E:/rabbitmq/work_queues/new_task.py", line 67, in publish
    self.publish(message=message)   File "E:/rabbitmq/work_queues/new_task.py", line 67, in publish
    self._channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.rabbit_mq_server.exchange,   File "E:\rabbitmq\venv\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 2242, in basic_publish
    self._channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.rabbit_mq_server.exchange,   File "E:\rabbitmq\venv\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 2242, in basic_publish
        self._impl.basic_publish( self._impl.basic_publish(  File "E:\rabbitmq\venv\lib\site-packages\pika\channel.py", line 421, in basic_publish

  File "E:\rabbitmq\venv\lib\site-packages\pika\channel.py", line 421, in basic_publish
    self._raise_if_not_open()   File "E:\rabbitmq\venv\lib\site-packages\pika\channel.py", line 1389, in
_raise_if_not_open
    self._raise_if_not_open()   File "E:\rabbitmq\venv\lib\site-packages\pika\channel.py", line 1389, in
_raise_if_not_open
    raise exceptions.ChannelWrongStateError('Channel is closed.') pika.exceptions.    raise exceptions.ChannelWrongStateError('Channel is closed.') ChannelWrongStateError: Channel is closed.pika.exceptions.ChannelWrongStateError:  Channel is closed.
```

Is it possible to send multiple message in parallel?
Is it possible to consume all those messages at one shot?

Answer (score 0):

Queues are independent of each other, the same for individual messages inside each queue. You can control which consumer is subscribed to which queue, though, but that's it.

If the messages are sent and consumed in parallel, why not create a big message with all the payloads?